# How to align navbar item to bottom in bootstrap react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

[Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0riK8.png)

I have a bootstrap react sidebar(check attachment), but how would I go about aligning few items bottom-up way instead of top-down? In the attachment, I would like bottom two items(FAQ and Contact) lined up to bottom of screen.

```
<Nav className="flex-column pt-2">
      <p className="ml-3">Menus</p>

      <Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Link href="/">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTable} className="mr-2" />
          Dashboard
        </Nav.Link>
      </Nav.Item>

      <Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Link href="/">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faWarehouse} className="mr-2" />
          Inventory
        </Nav.Link>
      </Nav.Item>

      <Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Link href="/">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTruck} className="mr-2" />
          Create Order
        </Nav.Link>
      </Nav.Item>

      <SubMenu
        title="Manage"
        icon={faCopy}
        items={["Sales", "Employees"]}
      />

     *//I want to put these two to bottom*
      <Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Link href="/">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faQuestion} className="mr-2" />
          FAQ
        </Nav.Link>
      </Nav.Item>

      <Nav.Item className="align-items-end">
        <Nav.Link href="/">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPaperPlane} className="mr-2" />
          Contact
        </Nav.Link>
      </Nav.Item>


    </Nav>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to separate the bottom two nav items and push them down to the bottom of the sidebar correct?

Comment: @Mizzy That's correct. I thought align-self-end or align-items-end would do the trick, but no luck.

Comment: You can wrap items in divs such as 'top-nav-items' and 'bottom-nav-items' then add justify-content-between to <Nav className="flex-column pt-2 justify-content-between">. If you create a reproducable code we can help you easily by editing your code [How do I create a React Stack Snippet with JSX support?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support)